# Sharing Singleton dbContext across Repositories using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, ninject

I read through quite some posts regarding similar topics. I have a part repository

```
    public class EFPartRepository : IPartRepository
    {
        private ItemDBEntities dbContext = null;
        public EFPartRepository(ItemDBEntities dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }
    }
```

I will use another repository named image repository

```
public class EFUploadedImageRepository : IUploadedImageRepository
{
    private ItemDBEntities dbContext = null;
    public EFUploadedImageRepository(ItemDBEntities dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }  
}
```

Since they will be used in the same request, I want them to share a singleton of dbContext during a request, so there won't be any exception "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Here is my original Ninject registion code.

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IPartRepository>().To<EFPartRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IUploadedImageRepository>().To<EFUploadedImageRepository>();
    }
```

So my question is, where is the best place to initialize this singleton, so it can be easily used by different repositories globally? And how to declare it? (The worst case is to always pass dbContext as parameter during each call).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to bind a singleton, simply do:
`kernel.Bind<ItemDBEntities>.To<ItemDBEntities>().InSingletonScope();`

However, you might want to consider the implications of this.
The `SingletonScope`, by definiton, will live for as long as kernel lives. So unless you are re-creating the kernel somewhere in the lifecycle of your app, the underlying database connection will stay open for that entire lifecycle.
Any SQL implementation will have a limited (even if very large) number of connections available (typically constrained by the number of TCP sockets available). This means that if that many copies of your app are running, no more can be run.

Also, this approach will force the connections to be long living. How will this recover? what if an exception is thrown in one repository causing the singleton db context to have a corrupt state?

A much more regular approach is to setup a repository with a context to be created once in resolution scope.

If you want to share an underlying context, then create a `IMyDBContext`, register that in the resolution scope (e.g. for web -> request scope) and then inject to both repositories. They will have the same context and entities can be shared across both, but the connection will be recreated for each resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try. Probably I should have a dbContext container, and make it as a singleton, shared by all repositories. This container has a dbConext set to null initially. When a request comes, The controller constructor will get one repository, and create the dbContext so it will be accessible by all repositories since the container is shared. And it will be destroyed once the request is ended.